# Partitioning a list given total partitions and partition number

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

Suppose I'm given a list of items:

> [ A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J ]

I'm asked to split these into 3 lists, and take the second list:

> [ A, B, C, D ] **[ E, F, G ]** [ H, I, J ]

How would I do this?

I'm thinking the function would look like

```
public List<Item> SplitItems(
    List<Item> items, 
    int totalPartitions, 
    int partitionNumber) { }
```

I'm able to get the list if the `partitionNumber` is 1 (the first set) using calculations involving the modulo operation of the `totalPartitions` and the `partitionNumber`, but I'm having issues getting the list of `partitionNumber` 2 and above.

---

@Blorgbeard: Here's the code that I have so far. Again, I'm only able to handle the first partition:

```
int itemsCount = items.Count;
int setCount = itemsCount/totalPartitions + ((itemsCount%totalPartitions >= partitionNumber) ? 1 : 0);
return webItems.Take(setCount).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the rule for splitting when there are extra items?  Always in the first partition?  split across the first partitions?  You're splitting 10 items into 3 groups, which doesn't break evenly...

Comment: ^ after you know the rules are well defined, you can easily calculate the start index and end index of the needed sublist and use `Skip` and `Take` to get that sublist.

Comment: @ReedCopsey If I have 10 items split into 3 sets, it would be [1-4],[5-7],[8-10]. If I have 11 items, it would then be [1-4],[5-8],[9-11]

Comment: Why not show us the code you've got already?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Added what I have so far. I'm having issues determining how much to "skip" on subsequent sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int smallPartitionSize = list.Count / totalPartitions;
int remainder = list.Count % totalPartitions;
int selectedPartitionSize = smallPartitionSize + (partitionNumber <= remainder) ? 1 : 0;
var start = (partitionNumber - 1) * smallPartitionSize + Math.Min(remainder, partitionNumber - 1);
return list.Skip(start).Take(selectedPartitionSize);
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the "Extra' items - note the example puts "D" in partition 1...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This fails for me for `SplitItems([10 items], 3, 1)` and `SplitItems([11 items], 3, 2)`

Comment: Actually, this is correct. You just missed out on one thing: `partitionNumber < remainder` should be `partitionNumber <= remainder`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to create a collection of evenly distributed numbers 0-2 and `Zip` it with your items:

```
var items = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };
var n = items.Length;

var partitioner = Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select (e => (e * 3) / n );
// Values: { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2 }

var result = partitioner.Zip(items, (i,s) => new {i,s})
                        .Where(z => z.i == 1).Select(z => z.s).ToList();
```

Comment: This is interesting approach. However, I can't use it since it uses `.Zip` and I'm only using `.NET 3.5`. Very cool though!

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the tag. It shouldn't be too hard to write your own `Zip` extension method in .Net 3.5. Anyway, I think I would also go for an out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static List<T> SplitItems<T>(
    List<T> items,
    int totalPartitions,
    int partitionNumber)
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    int partitionIndex = partitionNumber - 1;
    int size = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)items.Count / totalPartitions);
    result.AddRange(items.Skip(size * partitionIndex).Take(size));
    return result;
}
```